# Ionic 3 Http API Error

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to connect a MySQL DB to my Ionic app and a PHP Restful API. I tested the API with Postman and it is working just fine, in order to implement it in Ionic I did the following, I first made a provider named Authservice:

i tried the below solution it did not work

[Ionic 3 Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329963/ionic-3-uncaught-in-promise-object-object?rq=1)

```
signup() {
//REST API connection for Siging up a new customer
//this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
//console.log(this.userData);
this.authServiceProvider.postData(this.userData, "signup").then((result) => {
  this.responseData = result;
  if(this.responseData.userData) {
    console.log(result);
    //localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
}, (err) => {
  //connection failed error message
  console.log("something went wrong");
});
}
```

After clicking on signup button in signup.html page, the above signup will get executed and "something went wrong" is printed in the console. But I am able to do post request using POSTMAN

postData fucntion :

```
postData(credentials, type) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  let headers = new Headers();
  this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: new HttpHeaders() }).subscribe(res => {
    resolve(res);
  }, (err) => {
    reject(err);
  });
})
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help. Also share _your code_

Comment: @suraj rao i have edited the question and added code

Answer (score 0):

```js
postData(credentials, type) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  let headers = new Headers();
  this.http.post(apiUrl+type, credentials, { headers: new HttpHeaders() }).subscribe(res => {
    resolve(res);
  }, (err) => {
    reject(err);
  });
})
}
```

### Try This